# is spontaneous magnetization and magnetic susceptibility a thermodynamic properties?

Tags: thermodynamics, ferromagnetism

Are spontaneous magnetization and magnetic susceptibility a thermodynamic property? How do you determine whether a property is thermodynamic or not?

Comment: Upvote for this question. Never I'll understand why somebody downvotes and not leave a comment or better answer the question. From Wikipedia: "Thermodynamics is a branch of science concerned with heat and temperature and their relation to energy and work." So both spontaneous magnetization and magnetic susceptibility are not direct related to thermodynamics. On the other hand IF one would be able to design a effectic working maschine which produce electric energy from an oscillating magnetic field which will be induced by temperature fluctuations, perhaps it will be related to thermodynamics.

Answer (score 1):

A macroscopic magnetic system is a thermodynamic system like that of a hydrostatic system. The former is described by the thermodynamic variables $(\textbf{H},\textbf{M},T)$ and the latter by $(P,V,T)$. Therefore, magnetization $\textbf{M}$ (not necessarily spontaneous) is a thermodynamic property and it's the analog of volume $V$ for a hydrostatic system or a fluid. The magnetic field $\textbf{H}$ is the analog of fluid pressure $P$. The susceptibility is a response function for magnetic systems and is the analog of the compressibility of a fluid system.

If by thermodynamic property you mean gross property of the system then yes. Both the magnetization and susceptibility are properties belonging to the system as a whole.

But if by thermodynamic property you mean *thermodynamic coordinates* or *state variables* then those are the set of macroscopic quantities required to completely describe the state of the system at a particular instant of time in equilibrium. They are $(\textbf{H},\textbf{M}, T)$ for a magnetic system.

Comment: So are $H$ and $M$ state variables?

Comment: @Deepakms Yes. For a magnetic system.